# How to calculate derivative by element from matrices

Tags: matrices, derivatives, symmetric-matrices

I have a matrix $\Sigma$ given by
\begin{equation*}
\Sigma = \begin{bmatrix}
\phi_{11} &\phi_{12}\\
\phi_{12} & \phi_{22}
\end{bmatrix}
\end{equation*}

I'd like to calculate $\frac{\partial y^T\Sigma y}{\partial \phi_{11}}$,where $y$ is a vector.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have:
$$\partial y^T\Sigma y=\phi_{11} y_1^2+(\phi_{12}+\phi_{21}) y_1y_2+\phi_{22}y_2^2$$
so:
$$\frac{\partial y^T\Sigma y}{\partial \phi_{11}}=y_1^2=y^T A y$$
where:
$$A=\begin{bmatrix}1&0\\0&0 \end{bmatrix}$$

Comment: Thanks for your answer. How to solve when is $\Sigma^{-1}$ instead $\Sigma$?